# Cannot telnet to private IP or to port

Tags: centos, tcp, postgresql, telnet, firewalld

**What specific changes need to be made so that a CentOS 7 installation at local IP `192.168.1.6` can `telnet` to another CentOS 7 installation at another local IP `192.168.1.5`?**

As you can see, `192.168.1.6` IS ABLE TO PING `192.168.1.5` as follows:

```
[root@localhost /]# ping 192.168.1.5
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.515 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.565 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.5 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.515/0.540/0.565/0.025 ms
```

But `telnet` FROM `192.168.1.6` TO `192.168.1.5` fails as follows:

```
[root@localhost /]# telnet 192.168.1.5
Trying 192.168.1.5...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.5: No route to host
```

And `telnet` FROM `192.168.1.6` TO `port 5432` at `192.168.1.5` also fails as follows:

```
[root@localhost /]# telnet 192.168.1.5:5432
telnet: 192.168.1.5:5432: Name or service not known
192.168.1.5:5432: Unknown host
[root@localhost /]#
```

PostgreSQL is running at `192.168.1.5`, and should be receiving `telnet 192.168.1.5:5432`.  Therefore, I added the following line to `pg_hba.conf` BEFORE running the above:

```
host    all    all    192.168.1.6/24    trust
```

And I restarted PostgreSQL before running the above `ping` and `telnet` by typing `systemctl restart postgresql`.

Similarly, before running the above `ping` and `telnet` commands, I also created the following firewall rules on `192.168.1.5`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5432/tcp
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.1.6/32
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also, I confirmed that PostgreSQL is running at `port 5432` with the following command typed in the terminal of `192.168.1.5`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ss -l -n | grep 5432
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 71466                 * 0
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 71468                 * 0
tcp    LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:5432                  *:*
tcp    LISTEN     0      128     ::1:5432                 :::*
[root@localhost ~]#
```

---

**@roaima's suggestions:**

---

Per @roaima's suggestion, I tried the following, but am still not able to connect:

From 192.168.1.6, I sent:

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet 192.168.1.5 5432
Trying 192.168.1.5...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.5: No route to host
```

And on 192.168.1.5, the `tcpdump` of the receiving end of the `telnet` request was:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 5432 or arp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:52:49.309526 IP 192.168.1.6.53328 > localhost.localdomain.postgres: Flags [S], seq 3210933916, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 629624820 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:52:54.312716 ARP, Request who-has localhost.localdomain tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
16:52:54.312750 ARP, Reply localhost.localdomain is-at 52:54:00:ef:35:18 (oui Unknown), length 28
^C
3 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Similarly, from 192.168.1.6 I sent the following telnet to the IP level only:

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet 192.168.1.5
Trying 192.168.1.5...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.5: No route to host
[root@localhost ~]#
```

And on 192.168.1.5, the `tcpdump` of the receiving end of the `telnet` request was:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 5432 or arp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
//THESE 2 LINES PRINTED BEFORE 2ND TELNET WAS RUN: 16:58:11.619638 ARP, Request who-has gateway tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
//THESE 2 LINES PRINTED BEFORE 2ND TELNET WAS RUN: 16:58:11.619940 ARP, Reply gateway is-at b8:ec:a3:11:74:6e (oui Unknown), length 46
16:58:35.555570 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
16:58:35.555753 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.6 is-at 52:54:00:ab:31:40 (oui Unknown), length 28
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[root@localhost ~]#
```

---

**@cutrightjm's suggestions:**

---

On `192.168.1.5`, I typed the following in one Putty session:

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost 5432
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Simultaneously, in a separate Putty session to `192.168.1.5`, I saw no results from the `tcpdump`, as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 5432 or arp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[root@localhost ~]#
```

---

**@JeffSchaller's Suggestions:**

---

Per @JeffSchaller's suggestions, I ran the following commands on `192.168.1.6`.  Note that this is CentOS 7, which has replaced `netstat` with `ss`, and which has replaced `iptables` with `firewalld`:

`ss -rn` produced 90 lines of output.  Can you suggest a meaningful `grep` or other filter to reduce the output to the allowable amount to add to a posting?

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -Ln
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.


[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 8080/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

[root@localhost ~]#
```

I also ran the following commands on `192.168.1.6`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.6  metric 100

[root@localhost ~]# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ab:31:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 133013sec preferred_lft 133013sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feab:3140/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@localhost ~]#
```

---

**Removing Firewalls On Both Machines**

---

As an extreme test, I removed the firewalls on both `192.168.1.5` and `192.168.1.6` by typing `yum remove firewalld` and `yum remove iptables` on both machines.  I then validated both removals as follows:

On `192.168.1.5` :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status firewalld
Unit firewalld.service could not be found.
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L -n
-bash: /sbin/iptables: No such file or directory
```

On `192.168.1.6` :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status firewalld
Unit firewalld.service could not be found.
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L -n
-bash: /sbin/iptables: No such file or directory
```

Next, I typed `tcpdump -i eth0 port 5432 or arp` on `192.168.1.5`, followed by typing `telnet 192.168.1.5 5432` on `192.168.1.6`.

The result of the telnet was the following refusal message printed on `192.168.1.6`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet 192.168.1.5 5432
Trying 192.168.1.5...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.5: Connection refused
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Simultaneously, the `tcpdump` printout on `192.168.1.5` from the `telnet` call from `1.6` was:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 5432 or arp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:25:11.349238 ARP, Request who-has localhost.localdomain tell gateway, length 46
10:25:11.349261 ARP, Reply localhost.localdomain is-at 52:54:00:ef:35:18 (oui Unknown), length 28
10:25:14.391222 IP 192.168.1.6.53344 > localhost.localdomain.postgres: Flags [S], seq 3043089625, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 692769902 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:25:14.391265 IP localhost.localdomain.postgres > 192.168.1.6.53344: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3043089626, win 0, length 0
10:25:19.395578 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
10:25:19.396039 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.6 is-at 52:54:00:ab:31:40 (oui Unknown), length 28
^C
6 packets captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[root@localhost ~]#
```

To determine whether or not PostgreSQL is listening on `port 5432`, I typed the following two commands on `192.168.1.5`:

Note that **`firewalld` and `iptables` are both still removed while the following commands are run**:

First, I viewed the `pg_hba.conf` file in `192.168.1.5` to see that there is a rule to trust `192.168.1.6`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
# LOTS OF # COMMENTED LINES OMITTED HERE FOR BREVITY
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.1.6/24          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Next, I typed the following `netstat` command on `192.168.1.5` to see if there is a rule for `port 5432`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      943/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25166/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1483/master
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:45228         :::*                    LISTEN      19089/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          :::*                    LISTEN      14338/java
tcp6       0      0 :::7990                 :::*                    LISTEN      19089/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      943/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      25166/postgres
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7992          :::*                    LISTEN      19066/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7992                :::*                    LISTEN      19066/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1483/master
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36122         :::*                    LISTEN      19089/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8095                 :::*                    LISTEN      14338/java
tcp6       0      0 :::5701                 :::*                    LISTEN      19089/java
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Can you telnet localhost on 5432?

Comment: @cutrightjm Thank you.  Please see the results of your suggestion, which I just posted at the end of the OP.

Comment: The output of `netstat -rn` would be useful -- from the .6 host. Odd that you can ping it but have no tcp route.

Comment: You don't have .5 as a local IP on .6, do you?

Comment: @JeffSchaller .5 and .6 are each virtual machines whose IP addresses are assigned by a hardware firewall based on their MAC addresses. I can answer any questions now using my phone. I will be able to post results of any diagnostic commands such as your netstat -rn when I am back at my computer later.

Comment: I wonder also if the .6 host has iptables rules that aren't allowing those outbound ports. Check iptables -Ln and any firewall logs

Comment: @JeffSchaller Please see **EDIT** at the end of my OP with results of your suggestions.  Remember this is CentOS 7.  Also, can you suggest a filter for the `netstat -rn` (this has been deprecated in favor of `ss -rn`)?

Comment: Sorry, looks like that'd be "ip route "

Comment: And ip addr show -- to confirm that .5 isn't living on .6

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just added results of `ip route` and `ip addr show` to the end of my OP.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: (@JeffSchaller) That should be `iptables -L -n` or `iptables -nL` because `iptables -Ln` treats the `n` as a (bogus) chain. But I believe `iptables` and/or `firewall-cmd` on the target (1.5) is more useful than source (1.6) because the first `tcpdump` on 1.5 shows SYN arriving but no TCP response not even RST, and 1 packet filtered which could be ICMP. But even if that is due to firewall, `ss` on 1.5 shows postgresql listening on 127.1 and ::1 not the external address, which will also prevent the desired connection.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `iptables -L -n` produced 166 lines of output.  Can you suggest some sort of filter to narrow the results to only those lines which will help in this case?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just posted results at the end of the OP of **completely uninstalling firewalls on both machines**.  Does this help you narrow the problem?  Or see any possible solutions?

Comment: `192.168.1.5: Connection refused` leads directly to dave_thompson_085's suggestion that postgres isn't listening on an external address

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just posted the `pg_hba.conf` and `netstat` results at the end of my OP to test whether postgres is listening.  Can you please take a look?  Does this confirm or deny your assessment?  Can you please suggest a next step?

Comment: short of completely removing the firewalld package, you could have just `systemctl stop firewalld`

Comment: I don't know much about postgresql, but according to this [random internet page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/) you also have to edit postgresql.conf to change `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: @JeffSchaller You are right.  Adding `listen_addresses = '192.168.1.5, localhost'` to `postgresql.conf` got the database connection from `192.168.1.6` to work.  Then reinstalling and restarting `firewalld` and `iptables` on `192.168.1.5` still enabled it to work.  The problem has now been isolated to the `192.168.1.6` installation of `firewalld` because reinstalling/restarting `firewalld` on `192.168.1.6` causes the connection to fail, while stopping `firewalld` on `192.168.1.6` makes the connection work again.  I need to translate @roaima's suggestion into `firewalld` to finish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem was that you were using the wrong syntax for the `telnet` command. Running `man telnet` will show you that the syntax is something like this:

```
telnet <host> [<port>]
```

So in your case, you should run this:

```
telnet 192.168.1.5 5432
```

---

A second problem is that you have a firewall rule on each host preventing *outbound* traffic to 5432/tcp. (And probably other ports too.) The error message, "No route to host", is generated by an `iptables --j REJECT` rule in the `OUTPUT` chain that has `--reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`. Here is an example of creating such a rule:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

This satisfies the situation where the route clearly exists because `ping` succeeds, but where your `telnet` session fails. You yourself can check this with the command `iptables --line-numbers -nvL` (not `iptables -Ln`, which tries to list the rules for the chain `n`).

Two temporary fixes to confirm that traffic really can be established are

- Disable the firewall on both systems entirely
- Run these two commands on both systems (you can delete them afterwards by replacing `-I` with `-D`)

  ```
  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --src 192.168.1.5/30 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 192.168.1.5/30 -j ACCEPT
  ```

I'm not (yet) sufficiently familiar with the CentOS 7 firewall tool to give you a full solution for that. I can go digging or maybe someone else might like to edit this answer to provide that information.

Comment: I just posted results at the end of the OP of **completely uninstalling firewalls on both machines**.  Does this help you narrow the problem?  Or see any possible solutions?

Comment: @CodeMed removing `iptables` doesn't remove the firewall from your systems, it just removes the user interface. Please re-install that and run `iptables -nvL` to demonstrate (at least to yourself) that the POLICY is ACCEPT for the INPUT and OUTPUT chains, and that these chains are empty.

Comment: Glad you are online.  I isolated the problem to `192.168.1.6`, per the last comment under the OP.  I have questions for you that we could perhaps isolate in a series of comments here now if you are online.

Comment: Thank you and +1.  I am able to telnet to `.1.5` now after adding `listen_addresses = '192.168.1.5, localhost'` to `postgresql.conf`.  The problem was not the firewall, but your syntax suggestion helped move us towards the solution.  I am still not able to make a connection from a web app on `1.6` to the database at `1.5:5432`, but that is out of scope for the present question.

Comment: @CodeMed based on the error messages you showed in your question, it *was* related to the firewall. The last part of the puzzle was to have PostgreSQL listening, but the other parts were also necessary.

Comment: The '1.5' firewall already had a rule to accept TCP connection on the database's port. So the only missing piece was the database config. I did not need your iptables code because CentOS 7 uses firewalld.  ... There is a remaining firewalld question on the 1.6 box but it is only at the Java level. Telnet works now that this OP is resolved.

Comment: @CodeMed You would have received "connection refused" if it had simply been a daemon not listening. You got "no route to host", which in your scenario was indicative of a firewall rule blocking outbound traffic.

Comment: I had not included the --permanent argument to the firewall-cmd statement, so the rule did not survive restarting firewalld, and needed to be reentered. But still, the database config was the true problem. .... Also, iptables is legacy code from obsolete historical artefacts and does not apply to modern operating systems like RHEL7.

Comment: @CodeMed the firewall layer is implemented in the kernel and in user space as `iptables`. Tools like `firewalld` are an abstraction layer on top of that. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Introduction_to_firewalld